# Find next record within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Post` model that `belongs_to` a `Group` model. `Group`-s can have many `Post`s. Each `Post` has a number associated with it (1-5), and each `Group` has five posts numbered 1-5. I want a previous/next button to scroll through each `Post` in a `Group`.

This is what I have so far:

**post.rb**

```
def next_post
  Post.where(group_id: group.id).find_each do |post|
    post.where("number > ?", number).first
  end
end
```

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Next", group_post_path(@group, @post.next_post.first) %>
```

I get an error `undefined method 'where' for #<Post:0x007f8a7a8613c8>`.

Not too sure what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next_post` can be:

```
def next_post
  group.posts.where("number > ?", number).order(:number).first
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= link_to "Next", group_post_path(@group, @post.next_post) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem which provides many facilities including your requirement. It is really handy and you might need to check for post if it is the last one or first one then their respective previous and next should not appear else it will generate error.